# How to filter query based on page meta keys and/or title?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Beaver Builder with WordPress and am using Advanced Posts to display my custom post types. I have 6 teams and about 30 players that belong to each team. I want to display the team's roster on the team page but can't filter by team when selecting players to show.

I found this method: https://www.ultimatebeaver.com/docs/filter-query-parameters-advanced-posts/

But I am having trouble comparing the meta keys between players and teams and don't know where to begin.

This is what I have so far:

```
global $post;
$current_team = $post->post_name;

if ( $settings->id == 'team-roster' ) {
     $args['meta_key']       = 'team'; 
     $args['posts_per_page'] = '30'; 
     $args['meta_query']     = 
            array( 
                   'key'     => 'team',
                   'value' => '$current_team',  
                   'compare' => '=',                        
            ); 
 } 
 return $args;
```

I am trying to compare to the page slug, which is the same as the values stored in the meta_key.

I would like each team page to show the players on the team as well as use this same module on the players page to show the rest of the players. Open to other ideas as well if this isn't the right method.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand but you can have multiple queries using the `relation` parameter with `meta_query` but there are also other ways possibly to go about this. Can you post the code you have so far so we can see we the problem lies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using categories to filter instead of the relationship meta_key field. Found out that the relationship field is stored as an array so it wasn't comparing correctly. Here's my solution:

```
global $post;
$current_team = $post->post_name;

if ( $settings->id == 'team-roster' ) {

     $args['posts_per_page'] = '50'; 
     $args['tax_query']     = 
            array( 
                array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'category',
                   'terms' => $current_team,
                   'field' => 'slug',
                )                        
            ); 
 } 
 return $args;
```